# Is using tf-idf for classification task like sentiment analysis task correct?

Tags: machine-learning, document-classification

I often see people use tf-idf vectorization in text classification task like sentiment analysis. From my understanding, it penalizes the score of the words that appear in a lot of documents.(inverse document frequency) Often we ignore the words that have more than 0.5 df.

However, let's say I am doing sentiment analysis, and I have a word which occurs in every document of +ve review and zero or very few times in documents with -ve reviews. So, that word  is good indicator for my classifier and high document frequency definitively points to a particular category. So, in my opinion, it is counter intuitive to use penalize the high document frequency.

So is it a good idea to use tf-idf matrix for text classification tasks?

Answer (score 3):

tf-idf vectors are only one kind of vectorizer. You're free to try many others. The scenario above is possible, but you'll find that machine learning is much more about real datasets than theoretical guarantees.

In practice tf-idf works quite well, but it's not radically different from say a count vectorizer. There are also nearly a dozen different ways of specifically weighting both your tf, and idf components to add robustness to certain word distributions such as those you've proposed above.

In Machine Learning you shouldn't think of "good" or "bad" ideas, you should run an experiment and determine what the effect on the model performance is.

Answer (score 1):

First don't ignore terms higher than 0.5 idf for classification.

It depends on how you build up the +ve. If that word is in every document and you count every occurrence as frequency then the TF to IDF is a wash (if you normalize TF and IDF on the same basis). You typically don't normalize tf and idf on the same basis but still the high tf in one training set is not totally washed out by the idf.

You may want to look at naive bayes

Comment: what does is a wash mean? and with "You may want to look at naive bayes" are you suggesting to drop naive bayes?

Comment: Wash = cancel out.   Look = consider.

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy behind tf-idf is about identifying words that are specific to the documents you are trying to discriminate. If you want to distinguish between a set of documents, a word that occurs a lot in one document and never in any other is very good for disriminating.

Here if you want to apply the same philosophy, it would translate to the power of the words to discriminate between positive and negative classes. So you would instead penalize a word that is common to both classes. But that's actually what many algorithms will do implicitly. For instance if you use a naive bayes, it will detect those words while training and give the appropriate score.